# Mirroring Odd Bits of an Register

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bitwise-operators

Does anyone know how to mirror bits in NASM/8086?

Here is an example:

`10100001` after mirroring => `10000101`

The problem is more complicated, because I should mirror **ONLY the odd bits** of a register:

That means:

```
       10100001 => 00001011
       76543210 => 76543210
```

i.e. 1 <=> 7 and 3 <=> 5

Comment: Is this just for 8 bit values, or do you also need it for 16, 32, etc ?

Comment: @PaulR I fear he needs it for homework :-(

Comment: Yes, it is generally, not only for 8 Bit Registers!

Comment: @drhirsch: you could be right - it seems like an unusual thing to want to do, other than as a homework exercise

Comment: @Asam: No problem, but you should tag your post as `homework` and also state what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you! I´m new here :| Next time I will be more explicitly. Sorry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious algorithm would appear to be:

- create mask of even bits (`mask = 01010101...01010101`)
- extract even bits into a temporary (`temp = src AND mask`)
- mask out even bits from source register (`src = src AND NOT mask`)
- reverse bits in source register ([plenty of existing algos for this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel))
- shift reverse bits left by 1 so that they are still in odd locations (`src = src SHL 1`)
- re-insert even bits (`src = src OR temp`)

Of course if this is just for 8 bit values then you could just use a pre-computed 256 element LUT.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find out another way to solve the problem. Your Answer was very good, but the algorithm that you linked me yesterday it´s hard to implement, when you have only few minutes to solve the problem. I have not specified, but this homework was in fact an exam problem, with limited amount of time.

I think that the algorithm from Stanford University it´s more optimized but a little difficult to implement, or am I wrong?!

So, here is my Ideea:

```
MOV EAX,2862962005  ; Register where the odd bits must be mirrored
                    ; Initialised with an random Number as example
                    ; Result should be putted again in EAX

ODD_MIRRORED:
PUSH EBX            ;put the values of the other registers on to the Stack
PUSH ECX            ;probably this registers hold valuable datas inside
PUSH EDX

MOV EDX,0           ;EDX is counter, form 0 to 31
MOV EBX,0           ;EBX holds the inverted odd bits during the process 
                    ;For Auxiliary use only

iteration:
ROR EAX,1           ;EVEN VALUE? JUMP: EAX rotated to the right
ROL EBX,1           ;                  EBX rotated to the left (for mirroring)
INC EDX             ;                  counter incremented

MOV ECX,0x00000001  ;ODD VALUE? USE mask and extract only one odd value 
                    ;from EAX at a given time
AND ECX,EAX         
OR EBX,ECX          ;put the value in EBX
ROR EAX,1           ;EAX rotated to the right
ROL EBX,1           ;EBX rotated to the left (for mirroring)
INC EDX             ;counter incremented again

CMP EDX,31          
JGE end             ;if counter is greater or equal 31 jump at the end of the program

JMP iteration

end:
                    ;now EAX was rotated to the initial position
AND EAX,0x55555555  ;we want only just to get away from old odd values with
                    ;the mask 0x55555555 (0101), which is deleting the odd values
OR EAX,EBX          ;finally we transfer the mirrored odd bits into EAX from the 
                    ;auxiliary variable EBX

POP EDX             ;restore EBX,ECX,EDX
POP ECX
POP EBX
RET
```

I verified this solution in NASM/8086 Assembler with various numbers and it works! :P

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so other will see your question has been answered and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: Well done - it looks like this is a simple "brute force" method, but so long as it works then that is probably all that matters.